# Run command, and then add results via SQLCMD

Tags: linux, bash, sqlcmd

I am trying to run a command in bash and then output the results to a DB using SQLCMD

The below is my partial script

```
commandResults=$(/home/techionadmin/ssh.sh ${d9} "${d5}")
newcmd=${commandResults}
ranattimestamp=$(date +%s)
echo ${newcmd}
sqlcmd -S SERVER -d DB-U USER-P PASSWORD-Q \ 
"SET NOCOUNT ON UPDATE micro_i_cmd_queue SET status='EXECUTED', result='${newcmd}', ran_at='$ranattimestamp' WHERE id='$d1'" -b
```

For example I am running a 'ls -l' command on a Linux machine and then wanting to place results in DB
The echo ${newcmd} line is all good, outputs all ok
But when i run the SQLCMD i get an error

```
 Unclosed quotation mark after the character string
```

Everything else works except this part

What I have tried is remove all newlines or carriage returns but no effect
is only works if i do as of below.

```
commandResults=$(/home/techionadmin/ssh.sh ${d9} "${d5}" | tr -d '\040')
```

Notice the  | tr -d '\040' at the end - so it removes all spaces and leaves newlines, tabs & returns
If I try to replace all spaces with a char like '~', i can then fix it on the server side, but it dos not work

HELP!!!!

Full output of error below

```
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'total 5260
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi 1791164 Nov 22  2018 2018-11-22-    101115_1280x1024_scrot.png
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi 1792668 Nov 22  2018 2018-11-22-    101123_1280x1024_scrot.png
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi    1412 Jun 17 13:18 checkver.sh
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi    4096 Nov 22  2018 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi    4096 Oct 10  2018 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi    4096 Oct 10  2018 Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi 1661676 Oct  9  2018 get-pip.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi    4096 Jan  8 12:35 Heartbeat
drwxr-xr-x  8 pi pi    4096 Dec  5  2011 i2c-tools-3.1.0
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi   66840 May  1  2012 i2c-tools_3.1.0.orig.tar.bz2
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi    4096 Oct 10  2018 MagPi
drwxr-xr-x  5 pi pi    4096 Jun 12 12:26 Micro-I
drwxr-xr-x 14 pi pi    4096 Jun 19 12:07 MicroI_Deployment
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi    4096 Oct 10  2018 Music
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi       0 Jul  1 14:54 nul
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi pi    4096 Oct 10  2018 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi p
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server tgitsupport, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'total 5260
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi 1791164 Nov 22  2018 2018-11-22-101115_1280x1024_scrot.png
-rw-r--r--  1 pi pi 1792668 Nov 22  201'.
```

Is there a special character after the 'total 5260' ????

Comment: I am not familiar with `sqlcmd`, but have done a lot with bash and `mysql`. Check the `sqlcmd --help` options (I presume your `-b` is `"batch"`), and also check for options similar to `--execute` and `--silent`. For `mysql`, `-B` is batch, and `mysql -Bse "SQL command;"` generally does the job. (not sure if `sqlcmd` requires the closing `';'`, but I could see that causing quote issues)

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of: echo ${newcmd}

Maybe it contains a ' in the string, and is prematurely closing your quotes at result='${newcmd}'

Comment: Hi rvillabl, Nope there is no ' char, i can only guess that when it gets to the SQLCMD part, there is a special char somwhere like a return so the SQLCMD is expecting a ' char to end the line - im not sure. If i clear all spaces it works, but its unreadable if I do.